# Excel VBA: Can I query external excel without opening the target file?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to omit the line ".Open" below but it said "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed", are there any methods to query the file without opening it?

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & "C:\data.xls" & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With
Set rs = cn.Execute("SQL statement here")
```

Comment: Why don't you want anything looking in the file?  And how do expect anything to return the contents of the file if you don't want anything looking in it?

Answer (score 0):

You open a connection, not the file itself. 
Thus, it is really what you need. 
Try the following and see that the file is not opened:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cn  As Object
    Dim rs  As Object

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & "C:\DB.xlsm" & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With

    Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]")

    Do Until rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields.Item(1), rs.Fields.Item(2)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'cn.Close <- you need this only if you work with some crazy guys, who do not
                'understand the open-close principle

End Sub
```

---

If the file is shared between many users, then a `ReadOnly` permission of the connection (simply change the `ConnectionString` as shown) can be used:

```
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & "C:\DB.xlsm" & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES application intent=ReadOnly"";"
    .Open
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used to think that the file was opened due to the ".Open" code. As I find that your codes are no different from mine, I do some investigation and find out that the file is opened since it is in a network drive. I move the file to my local drive and the file is not opening again.
Do you know what can I do if I must put the file in network drive?